# Cannot link library with cmake and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker, libsndfile

I cannot link external library to my project

I have the following `CMakeLists` file

```
add_executable(MyProg main.cpp)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(winlib)
message(STATUS "SND FILE ${libsndfile}")
# Link
target_link_libraries(
        MyProg
        libsndfile)
```

I have downloaded `libsndfile` library, however cmake was not able to resolve it using the `find_library` function.

So I copied and renamed `libsndfile-1.lib` to my source directory

And now my project structure looks as follows

```
--
----winlib
------libsndfile.lib
----main.cpp
----otherfiles
```

When I try to build the project I get the following error

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libsndfile.lib'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CMakeLists.txt   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\LINK 1
```

What is wrong with my project, how can I link this library ?

Comment: @drescherjm , no I have downloaded x64 version of the sndfile library

Comment: Do you mean you named it `libsndfile-1.lib`?

Comment: @drescherjm I renamed it to be `libsndfile.lib`

Answer (score 1):

[`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_library.html) takes a `PATHS` argument with which you can specify where to look for the library.

There is a special variable [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) which resolves to the current directory, which you can use to specify the local subdirectory `winlib`

**Example:**

```
add_executable(MyProg main.cpp)

find_library(
        LIB_SND_FILE 
        libsndfile
        PATHS 
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/winlib)

target_link_libraries(
        MyProg
        ${LIB_SND_FILE})
```